# Cordova Screen Orientation Lock iOS

Tags: cordova, screen, orientation, landscape

I am trying to lock the screen orientation landscape in iOS / iPad.

I have tried the following and added it to the config and nothing:

I have also installed this plugin:
    https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation

But, I am not entirely sure how to implement it. Do I just add code to the config file or do I add it to my index.html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coudn't find a solution via Cordova. I ended up just updating the settings via XCode manually.